# Adding to a table that shares an id with another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write a recipe application that allows you to show and create new recipes. When a user clicks add recipe they should get a form that shows attributes for the recipe like cook time, title, servings then at the bottom should be a button to add ingredients and taken to a form that alows you to enter an ingredient hit add and it adds the ingredient to a ingredient table thats connected to a recipe table that holds the previously mentioned information. then be able to hit a button that says add steps then taken to a form that allows you to input the steps and which number step it is and save this to the step table then when done you can hit add recipe all this is saved and refers to the same recipe id. then you can click on the name of the recipe and display all that data for that specific recipe.

I have been trying to find a video on working with multiple tables that are nested inside of each other and adding to them to refer to the same id but haven't found one that shows my exact problem. I have also looked for a similar stack overflow question to mine but haven't found on that is showing the same issue as I'm having.

These are the functions in my ingredients controller

```
  def new
     @ingredient = Ingredient.new
   end

def create
    @ingredient = Ingredient.new(ingredient_params)
    @ingredient.save
  end

  def ingredient_params
    params.permit(:item)
  end
```

This is my form for the recipe table with the link located at the bottom that i'm using to get to the next form but the form wont save the ingredients I have entered.

```
  <%= form_for(@recipes) do |f| %>
 <h2>Enter name of recipe</h2>
     <%= f.text_field :title, :required => 'required' %>
  <h2>How many does this serve</h2>
      <%= f.text_field :servings, :required => 'required' %>
   <h2>Enter prep time in minutes</h2>
      <%= f.number_field :prep_time, :required => 'required' %>

  <h2>Enter amount of time to cook in minutes</h2>
      <%= f.number_field :cook_time%>
 <h2> Select country of origin</h2>
      <%= f.country_select :origin %>
 <a href = "/ingredients/new">Add ingredients</a>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I think you may be confusing databases and tables. Rails apps usually just have one database containing different tables for each model. The rare cases where you have different databases are usually when you have to deal with stuff like writing to legacy database and are a PITA.

Comment: your right I am confuing databse with tables I will make an edit to my question to correct this thank you.

Comment: I think what you want is [accept_nested_attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) but it would help clarify things if you can write a high level description of what you are trying to accomplish. Write it as a user story and don't get stuck in the technical details. "When a user does A, they should see B, and be able to do C".

Comment: Alright ill do that thank you.